# What't the meaning of "thrive on" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I found this sentence in a book about anxiety and how to treat it. The author here is speaking about the fight-or-flight response of human body (see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fight-or-flight_response ). I don’t understand the meaning of the first sentence. What does it mean «thrive on adrenaline» here?

> Many of us thrive on adrenaline in fight-or-flight mode based on life-style, external demands, or the way we react to stressors. Although welcomed at moments of need, unmanaged excessive demand of adrenaline can drive imbalanced expression, which results in anxiety, panic attack, worry etc.

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary?

Comment: to survive heartily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"thrive on something" [means](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/thrive-on)

> to enjoy something or be successful at something, especially something that other people would not like
>
> Example: He thrives on hard work.

The text is basically saying that many of us are happy with normal amounts of adernaline; normal levels of stress improve our performance.

Comment: Maybe I asked the question in the wrong way... I don't get the construction of the sentence: what does it mean "based on life-style, external demands etc."? We are happy with adrenaline because it helps us to thrive when reacting to stressors, to whatever happens to us? Can you paraphrase the whole first sentence, please?

Comment: @Cicc, that means that the benefit of adrenaline is not unconditional. It depends on how we react to stressors, etc. Actually the second sentence clarifies the first one. So the first sentence could be rephrased as "Our life-style, external demands, or the way we react to stressors determine whether we thrive on adrenaline in fight-or-flight mode."